# Are there polls/studies of how much US voters are influenced by foreign policy?

Tags: united-states, foreign-policy

Have there been any polls or studies asking Americans how much their vote is influenced by foreign policy concerns?

For example, how much does the foreign policies of a president weigh on the choice of the average American voter? And more importantly, do major events in the Middle East have any importance to the average American?

Comment: I think this question is far too broad to be answerable (rather than debatable).  For instance, who is "the average American voter"?  You have groups that care about particular foreign policies, but which have diametrically opposite views on what the "correct" policy should be: does that mean they average out to not caring?

Comment: It's also extremely opinion-based.  What does "care" mean?  What's a "major" event?  Those are all highly subjective.

Comment: I think reframing your question to be more related to factors determining voting preferences (like one of your examples) would help it be reopened. Something along the lines of how much does foreign policy (versus domestic, versus personal factors) influence voters' choices.

Comment: I can’t find any polls or studies directly relevant. Of some relevance though are the regular studies pointing to significant gaps in US education re geography/politics. The gaps extend to college students and to important areas of US foreign policy. (Eg: https://www.earth.com/news/american-geographic-illiteracy-security-threat/). On the face of it, this indicates that the foreign policies of a president, viewed through a lens of ignorance by US voters, does not influence voting as it should do so (or perhaps inappropriately influences it).